# Should I use status code = 403 or keep it 200 if the sent value by ajax is not correct?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make a route in Flask to check the sent value by ajax from the user, and if the value (content) is empty should I return the status code = 403 and handle it with "error" function in ajax or return status code = 200 and handle it with "success" function. Although I have to use status code = 200 for correct value (content).

```
    # Get the content from the user..
    requestedData = request.get_json()
    content = requestedData["content"]

    # Check if the content is empty..
    if not content:
        return jsonify({"message": "Add a content."}), 403

    # Check if the new content is already exist..
    cr.execute("SELECT content FROM contents WHERE user_id=:user_id", {
                        "user_id": session["user_id"]})
    values = cr.fetchall()
    for row in values:
        if row[0] == content:
            return jsonify({"message": "Duplicated!."}), 403
   
    # for the correct value after adding it in the database.
    return jsonify({"message": "OK."}), 200
```

or all of if statements use status code = 200, but add another value for example number for checking in JavaScript to which response is this ?

Comment: You should generally return an error code if there is an error. That being said, 403 (Forbidden) doesn't look a good fit for your use case. You might consider 400 (Bad Request) instead.

Comment: OK. So I should use 400 error code for if statements those handle with error values form the user.
Thank you.  @Selcuk

Comment: It actually depends on your application. An empty request should most certainly return an error code (400). The second case (duplicated entry) is in a grey area. Does the client know if the content is duplicated? Should it retry with a new content? If the answer is no to both questions responding with a 200 is also acceptable as there is nothing else that needs to be done. There is no hard rule on this.

Comment: I got it, thank you again. @Selcuk